# Angularjs + directive Isolate two way data binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, isolate-scope

I try to update the list using directive template. But its not update the data after http request.

test.html:

```
<div ng-repeat=" comment in [{name:"A"},{name:"B"},{name:"C"}]">
    <div lookup-product-icon lookup="lookupProduct(comment)"   products="products"></div>
</div>
<div lookup-products></div>
....
```

Directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.directive('lookupProductIcon', function() {
    return {
        scope : {
            lookup : "&"
        },
        template : '<div  ng-click="lookup()">Use me!</div>',
    };
});

app.directive('lookupProducts', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'EA',
        transclude : false,
        scope : {
            products : '='
        },
        templateUrl : 'lists.html'
    };
});
```

Controller

```
$scope.products = [];
        $scope.lookupProduct = function(lists) {
                var details = {
                name : lists.name,
                host : $scope.host_name
            };
            productService.lookupProduct(details).then(function(data) {
                $scope.products = data.list;
                console.log($scope.products);
                //Here display the lists in developer tools.
            }).catch(function(data) {
                if (data.message) {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            });

        };
```

List.html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat = "product in products">    {{product.name}}    </li>
</ul>
```

Once I click the "Use me!" means then i need to send the http request and  then display the lists for the respective content in list.html.

lookupProduct function working but only thing is  the products not updating.

Details:

I added two directives. 
1. lookupProductIcon - Display the text. Once this text clicked means need to the http get request and then response need to update in list.html (lookupProducts directive)
2. lookupProducts - Here the the data not updating.

Comment: You define products inside lookup-products directive, but using in lookup-product-icon lookup. why?

Comment: I am using many pages this module. So i created lookup-product-icon.

Comment: Are you shure `lookup()` is launched? The one on `ng-click`. I say that because in some cases I had to call `$scope.apply()` when I add dinamic directivies.

Comment: I am sure i am getting the data after sucess. $scope.products = data.list;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lookupProducts` directive has a scope variable `products` that is not being passed in your html markup.

You need to pass in an array of products to your `lookupProducts` directive.

`<div lookup-products products="products"></div>`

Comment: Oh god. Its my mistake only. Thanks